# decimal.Parse(item.Value) throws FormatException with Listitems

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm having a very strange problem here.
I have created a `ListItem item = Currency.Items[Currency.SelectedIndex];`
Currency is for my  tag. Everything goes here okay. Item will get that value
what I have chosen in aspx page. But the problem occurs when I'm trying to convert `item.Value` to `decimal newAmount` with `decimal.Parse(item.Value)`.

Heres the code

```
protected void Convert_money(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal oldAmount;
    bool success = decimal.TryParse(US.Value, out oldAmount);
    if (success)
    {
        ListItem item = Currency.Items[Currency.SelectedIndex];
        string s = item.Value;
        decimal newAmount = oldAmount * decimal.Parse(s);
        // decimal newAmount = oldAmount * decimal.Parse(s);
        Result.InnerText = s;
    }
    else
        Result.InnerText = "error";
}
```

It throws : 
Input string was not in a correct format. 
Ive copied exactly from my book and searched for an answer but cant find a solution for here.

Comment: Debug and find whether the item.value getting as per you requirement or not.

Comment: Yes it did get right value. item.Value is 0.85 and it string s is getting the same value: 
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +11162815
   System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +172
   System.Decimal.Parse(String s) +25
   ASPHarjoitus.CurrencyConverter2.Convert_money(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \CurrencyConverter2.aspx.cs:33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the culture respectively locale that is used to parse the number. 
There is an [overload of the Parse method that takes an IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you should try.

If you are always using decimal points as separators, you could also use `decimal.Parse(s, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Wow, It worked when Ive added culture.NumberFormat, but anyway thanks!